# Reading code from Repository

Tags: octokit, octokit.net

I am new to Octokit.NET. Trying to use it to login to my repo and then get a particular repository in a WinRT 8.1 Universal app. Ultimately I want to read some .cs files in that repo as text. I am using following code to authenticate and get all repos. However I keep empty error message. Not sure if I am using the Octokit the right way-

```
 var credentials = GithubHelper.Credentials;
 var connection = new Octokit.Connection(new Octokit.ProductHeaderValue("dotnet-test-functional"),new Uri("https://mygit.github.com"))
 {
      Credentials = credentials
 };
 var octokitClient = new Octokit.GitHubClient(connection);

 IReadOnlyList <Octokit.Repository> repos = await octokitClient.Repository.GetAllForCurrent();
```

I would appreciate if someone can help me out with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Just for googlers, the octokit.net api now has Repository Contents APIs in it.

```
var AllContent  = await client.Repository.Content.GetAllContent(repo.Owner.Login, repo.Name);
```

To get unencoded text from a file, you can do this

```
var textOfFirstFile = AllContent[0].Content;
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about the specific exception here, but I'll walk you through the steps anyway.

The `baseAddress` overload on `GitHubClient` is for when you need to connect to a GitHub Enterprise environment. If you're just connecting to github.com, you don't need to specify it.

```
var client = new GitHubClient(new ProductHeaderValue("dotnet-test-functional"));
client.Credentials = GithubHelper.Credentials;
var repos = await client.Repository.GetAllForCurrent();
```

That should return you the repositories associated with the current user.

However the [Repository Contents APIs](https://developer.github.com/v3/repos/contents/) are not currently implemented (there's a [pull request](https://github.com/octokit/octokit.net/pull/434) in the queue where we've been discussing how to go about it, but it's not close to ready).

Comment: Thanks! I can now login. When do you think Repository Content API would be ready. Is there a work around for now that you would suggest.

Comment: No firm date, I'm afraid.